# Gridcolumn enable/disable

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

A have a checkbox column inside my grid. With another different chechbox I want to toggle the enabling and disabling of the checkbox column inside the grid. The checkbox column is the first column inside my grid.

I have done something like this:

```
onCheckBoxFieldChange() {
var testGrid = Ext.getCmp('testGrid');
var cm = testGrid.getView().getHeaderCt().getGridColumns();

if (newValue === true) {
    cm[0].setDisabled(true);
    cm[0].addCls('noClick');
}
else {
    cm[0].setDisabled(false);
    cm[0].removeCls('noClick');
}
 }
```

CSS:

```
.noClick {
pointer-events: none;
}
```

I have tried two approaches. One with the method `setDisabled` and the other with setting a CSS class. Both approaches did not work. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grid.getView().getHeaderCt().child('checkcolumn').setDisabled(newValue);
```

This will search for the grid's column whose type is `checkcolumn` then disable it.

Comment: I have a checkboxSelectionModel associated with the grid so this might not work.

Comment: I have checked wich class is attached to the first colmn and it is "x-column-header-checkbox" so I tried like this: grid.getView().getHeaderCt().child('.x-column-header-checkbox') but it did not work.